# Face-tracker to find eyes iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, face-detection

I used [the code from here](https://github.com/aptogo/FaceTracker) to find Face. Im trying to draw both the eyes and the face.
But I can only show both the eyes or the face depending which of the statements i write first. How to do this?

```
// Detect faces
std::vector faces;
_faceCascade.detectMultiScale(mat, faces, 1.1, 2, kHaarOptions, cv::Size(60, 60));
//Detect eyes
std::vector eyes;
_eyesCascade.detectMultiScale(mat, eyes, 1.1, 2, kHaarOptions, cv::Size(30, 30));
```

Here eyes.size() = 0. If i interchange the position of the two statements, i get eyes.size() = 2 and faces.size() = 0

Comment: Hi, 2vision2. Please clarify your goal. Are you trying to draw on a layer on top of the video capture or mask certain parts of the image so you only output the eyes/face? I ask because obviously facial features aren't mutually exclusive to one's face. I.e., hypothetically, what's the problem with just outputting a user's face?

Comment: @AlexSmith The above mentioned code (in my post) detects the face and draws a rectangle on the face image in live stream. Now my goal is to draw rectangles on the eyes.

Comment: Have you gotten any further than adding these two lines of code to the source's sample project? I would check to see you're checking the values _after_ they have been set. I believe you have the debugger set to break on the last of the two statements thus not having executed that line yet. And from my testing so far, I'm getting a value of 1 for both `eyes.size()` and `faces.size()`.

Comment: Also, can you provide your implementation of `- (void)displayEyes:forVideoRect:videoOrientation:` including its full method name?

Comment: @AlexSmith Sorry Am new to objective C. I haven't implemented displayEyes. I just added the two lines before display faces. I thought it would be enough. Thanks a lot for your help. If i get the implementation it would be great.

Comment: The implementation is up to you. There may be several ways of doing this. I would keep the original implementation of `-(void)displayFaces:...` and do another `dispatch_sync` from within displayFaces to process the eyes calling a new implementation for displayEyes. This would require you get rid of your existing eyes vector and to create your own `cv::CascadeClassifier eyeCascade` (or two ;-) ) variable local to that method. This should be more than enough information to get where you want to go. Good luck!

Comment: Actually, don't use `dispatch_sync` again. Just call your `-(void)displayEyes:` implementation however many times you believe is necessary (in case you can only see half of someone's face because it's turned to the side for example) if the FaceTracker code supports it.

Comment: @AlexSmith I have duplicated the displayFaces to displayEyes and now I achieved eye detection. Now my doubt is how to call only once dispatch_sync? I called it twice one for face and another for eye detection. Can you help me in this regard?

Comment: Few hints: 1. Try to use CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT flag - Haar cascade will start searching from biggest "window", usually this makes code much faster  
2. Search for both eyes using one cascade classifier - searching for each eye separately is much slower(even if you optimize it) and more complicated  
3. Search for eyes inside face(or even only in some part of face) - there is no point in searching for eyes outside the face

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If your goal is to retrieve face and eyes position on iOS, why don't you use CoreImage capabilities?

```
CIImage *image = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"image.jpg"]];

NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:CIDetectorAccuracyHigh, CIDetectorAccuracy, nil];

CIDetector *faceDetector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace context:nil options:options];

NSArray *features = [faceDetector featuresInImage:image];
for(CIFaceFeature* faceFeature in features)
{
    CGRect faceSize = faceFeature.bounds.size;
    PointF leftEyePosition;
    PointF rightEyePosition;
    PointF mouthPosition;

    if(faceFeature.hasLeftEyePosition)
        leftEyePosition = faceFeature.leftEyePosition;
    //do the same for right eye and mouth
}
```

It doesn't use OpenCV, but you get the mouth position for free.

Comment: 2vision2 wants to track faces in video - so better to set accuracy to `CIDetectorAccuracyLow`

Comment: @Stephane Delcroix I heard Opencv is much faster than CoreImage? IS that true?

Comment: @2vision2 this code is fast enough to de detect faces in real time and give good results. Opencv could be faster or not, you'd need to benchmark it.

Comment: Can I detect iris in live camera?

Answer (score 0):

It's logical to just copy the shared input parameters i.e. copy mat into mat2 and use that as the second input.

Answer (score 0):

Variable mat is an array and is passed by value. Inside the function the values inside mat change and thus whichever statement you put first is implemented properly which mat changes for the second statement. So create a deep copy of the variable mat, before either of the statements and use mat-copy variable in place of mat in the second statement.